# Paste multiple large csv files with different header order

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, scripting, csv

I have multiple large csv files in a folder and I am trying to rbind(concatenate) them into one csv. But, while doing this I want to make sure all column values go in an appropriate column after concatenating. I can't do this in R because of memory limitation. I am pretty much new to shell scripting and I know there might be some way to do that without taking all csv files into memory.

Eg.

```
> csv1
     A  B  C  D  E
     1  2  4  5  6
     4  5  7  8  9
     3  5  6  7  8
     2  3  4  5  8

> csv1
    C  B  E  D  A
    10 22 43 35 66
    14 15 37 48 99
    33 25 56 67 88

> Desired Output
         A  B  C  D  E
         1  2  4  5  6
         4  5  7  8  9
         3  5  6  7  8
         2  3  4  5  8
        66 22 10 35 43
        99 15 14 48 37
        88 25 33 67 56
```

My attempts:

I try to set column order in R for each file while saving and then use below code to concatenate. I want to know a way where I can do everything in linux shell.

**My Attempt:**

```
nawk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}' *.csv > result.csv


Any help is highly appreciated.
```

**Solution by RavindraSingh13-**

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
}
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     a[$i]=i};
  if(FNR==1 && FNR==NR){
     print};
  next
}
{
  for(j in a){
     printf("%s ",$a[j])}
  print ""
}
' csv1 csv2
```

But, in above solution it is skipping some rows while concatenating.

Comment: So... you have a solution that works for the example files you have provided, but does not work for your actual files? If that's the case, you need to figure out how your actual files differ from the examples - it's going to be hard for anyone here to guess

Answer (score 2):

GNU **`awk`** solution. Though, it'll map all values in memory.

`merge_by_headers.awk` script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" }
NR==1 || FNR==1{ 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) map[i] = $i; 
    c = NF; next 
}
NR==FNR{ 
    row_cnt = NR-1; 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[map[i]][row_cnt] = $i; 
    next 
}
{ 
    row_cnt += 1; 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[map[i]][row_cnt] = $i; 
}
END{
    delete map; h = ""; 
    for (k in a) h = (h? h OFS:"")k; 
    print h; 
    for (i=1; i<=row_cnt; i++) { 
        cnt = c; 
        for (k in a) printf "%d%s", a[k][i], (--cnt? OFS : ORS) 
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
awk -f merge_by_headers.awk 1.csv 2.csv | column -t
```

The output:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   2   4   5   6
4   5   7   8   9
3   5   6   7   8
2   3   4   5   8
66  22  10  35  43
99  15  14  48  37
88  25  33  67  56
```

Comment: sh: BEGIN{: command not found
sh: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 2: `    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){ map[i] = $i; }'

Comment: I am getting above error

Comment: @Rushabh, note, this is GNU awk solution, check if you have a proper awk implementation installed

Comment: linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1041 linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1043
  linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1044 linux-headers-4.4.0-1041-aws
  linux-headers-4.4.0-1043-aws linux-headers-4.4.0-1044-aws
  linux-image-4.4.0-1041-aws linux-image-4.4.0-1043-aws
  linux-image-4.4.0-1044-aws

Comment: I reran sudo apt-get install gawk

Comment: GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)

Comment: Ubuntu Version 16.04.3

Comment: @Rushabh if you are getting an error from `sh` ( rather than from `awk`) then it sounds like you are executing the script wrongly: did you follow the usage example `awk -f merge_by_headers.awk 1.csv 2.csv` provided?